# Is it possible to configure the Hyper modifier-key on Wayland?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, wayland

In X11 I'm using the Hyper key, is it possible to configure a hyper key for wayland?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper is the combination of CTRL, ALT and SUPER

At least that's how the [R_ALT-to-Hyper plugin](https://gitlab.com/oarmstrong/ralt2hyper/-/blob/master/ralt2hyper.c) for the HID evdev [Interception tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) does it.

The Evdev layer is lower than X11 and Wayland, so `Hyper` becomes available in whatever UI system you use.

Comment: IMHO, it is incorrect to consider a modifier to be the combination of other modifiers, as we are supposed to be able to use modifiers together (I expect to be able to use `CTRL+ALT+SUPER+a`, `HYPER+a`, and `CTRL+ALT+SUPER+HYPER+a`, all being different). At least, Emacs sees correctly `CTRL+Alt+SUPER+a` as `C-M-s-a` and `HYPER+a` as `H-a` on X11, which allows different actions. Note that (Emacs) `CONTROL+ALT+SUPER+HYPER+a` is seen as `C+H+M+s+a`.